# Polite way to ask

Tags: conditional-constructions, questions, politeness

I am writing an email to an important person to attend.
I would like to ask him about his schedule.
Is the following sentence correct and polite?

> I was wondering if you could give me more details of your flight so that I can meet you at the airport?

or I need to change "can" to "could" in order to use tense correctly?

Comment: That sounds perfect. No change is needed for could.. Or you can consider using "I would appreciate it if you could ~~~~

Comment: Alternatively you can use, "I would appreciate it if you could provide more details of your flight so that I can meet you at the airport."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add "can",
However, your construction of "details of your flight" is awkward. 
I would recommend one of the following:

"I was wondering if you could give me your flight details..."

or

"I was wondering if you could give me more details about your flight..."

Comment: I prefer would over could in this context. The person is probably capable of sharing their flight details; we're asking if they are willing to share them.

Comment: often in speech, "could" is used to mean the same as "would be willing to", as opposed to its literal meaning of "to be capable of".

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was incorrect - when I'm speaking I use them interchangeably quite often. I prefer more precise wording in formal writing.

Comment: "Would be willing" is certainly more formal, and will sound better in professional writing. Sorry, I misunderstood.